# Malayalam text along a circular path using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I want to place some Mayalam (or Sanskrit, Tamil) text along a circular arc path.  The following code does not work in Malayalam (or any other language)
and stalls; however it works perfectly well if the Text is in English language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\mala}[Script=Malayalam]{Rachana}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex,blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={\mala മലയാളം  മലയാളാം മലയാളം },text align=center}]
(4,0) arc [start angle=-60,end angle=80,radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For comparison, this is how the text of the output should look, though obviously drawn along a circular path:

[image]

The dotted circles of unicode combining characters are definitely wrong.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "stalls"? What is the particular error produced when you try to compile this code?

Comment: When I compile the file with xelatex, the following'message shows uop and things stall with no action.ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Comment: @Narayanaswami I updated my answer to avoid dotted circles

Answer (score 3):

the font command `\mala` upsets the path text, so I just moved it somewhere safer:

[image]

I changed font to one that I had installed, and removed the `xltxtra` package as it isn't really recommended these days.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\mala}[Script=Malayalam]{Kartika}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\mala
\draw[-latex,blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={മലയാളം  മലയാളാം മലയാളം },text align=center}]
(4,0) arc [start angle=-60,end angle=80,radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or again, with extra brace groups to keep combining combinations together. the last word seems particularly tricky, anywhere I tried to split it left unknown combinations and a dotted circle, but as is the last segment is rather "straight" for the path. probably someone who can read the language can make a better split.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\mala}[Script=Malayalam]{Kartika}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

{\mala മലയാളം  മലയാളാം മലയാളം}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\mala
\draw[-latex,blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={{മ}{ല}{യാ}{ളം}  {മ}{ല}{യാ}{ളാം} {മലയാളം} },text align=center}]
(4,0) arc [start angle=-60,end angle=80,radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It has probably split up unicode composing combinations hence the dotted circles, but I left as is for now, as I can't read the text so it's difficult for me to guess the correct output as separate letters.

Comment: Yes it has split up the composing combinations. This is a bad error and the provided output is definitely wrong, do you know of a fix?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle +1 for your excellent work.

Comment: @Au101 manually I would guess you can fix it by adding `{}` around each letter in the input, fixing automatically would mean digging in to the tikz text decoration code and making it not assume each character is a single token but to keep combining combinations together.  probably doable but would be easier if I knew tikz and/or Malayalam :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for that and for your work here :) It's a great answer, but the honest truth is I reckon it's important to deal with the unicode problem because having the dashed circles is so wrong you'd probably be better off giving up and doing it in transliteration/some other software so that really helps

Comment: FYI: `text={{മ}{ല}{യാ}{ളം}  {മ}{ല}{യാ}{ളാം} {മ}{ല}{യാ}{{ളം}} },text align=center}]` (for some reason double braces seem to be required around the last character) does produce the correct output, but the downside is I also get the error `*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug`. FYII: If your editor is set-up correctly it should be able to tell 1 letter combination from the next so that if you move the cursor along with the arrow keys it will highlight each combination in turn and should treat യാ as one (for example)

Comment: +1 Thanks =) FYIII (:P) if it helps: മ = ma, ല = la, യാ = yā, ളം = ḷam. So മലയാളം is Malayalam in Malayalam. I'm not sure exactly what the second word (malayāḷām) means, but it's not too important :P

Comment: Thanks.  the double braces around the offending characters solves the problem.  Since these text along paths are small sentences, I can manage those characters that use unicode combination glyphs with the double braces.

Comment: All thre words are the same - മലയാളം , so it is a simple typo in the second word.