# How can we write text along the circular path in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, text-decorations

Can somebody explain me the basics how can we do that?
Thanking you in advance

Comment: Search is your friend: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361916/malayalam-text-along-a-circular-path-using-tikz, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103892/how-to-fine-tune-rotation-of-text-along-circular-path, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179488/a-circular-table-where-the-rows-form-concentric-circles, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114562/circular-arrows-and-text-on-path, etc.

Comment: e.g., `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex,blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={It was the best of times, it was the worst of times},text align=center}]
(4,0) arc [start angle=-60,end angle=80,radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`